# Use Lambda to create static inner functions?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Is it possible to create static inner function using lambda?

Specifically, I want to do the following:

```
function myFunc(){
    Map<Integer, String> myMap = new HashMap <Integer, String> ();
    myMap.put(1,"A");
    String head = () -> myMap.get(1);
    myMap.put(1,"B");

    System.out.println(head);   // Should print B
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What's stopping you from calling `System.out.println(myMap.get(1))`?

Comment: Nothing.  The idea is to be able to re-use the code so I don't have to rewrite it twice.

Comment: Which code are you trying to reuse?

Comment: Well in this example, myMap.get(1).  But you can imagine any code could go in there.

Comment: @YongkeBillYu No, we can't imagine it. Your example doesn't demonstrate what you are actually trying to do and doesn't even have type consistency.

Comment: You can define `Supplier<String> s = () -> myMap.get(1);`, then call `System.out.println(s.get());`, though I can't say it's more elegant in your particular case...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All lambdas are inner functions. The one you wrote is a `Supplier<String>`:

```
Supplier<String> getHead = () -> myMap.get(1);
System.out.println(getHead.get());
```

You can see what types of functions exist by looking through the `java.util.function` package.

Note however that the standard way to accomplish this (since before lambdas) is simply to write a `private` method and call it, and the traditional style will have less overhead involved, though whether that overhead is significant is another question.

Comment: It works, although it's not as elegant as I had hoped.  Maybe the traditional method is better.

Comment: @YongkeBillYu There are times when lambda functions are useful and I don't think this is one of those times. Using them to do `Supplier<String> getHead = () -> myMap.get(1);` instead of `String head = myMap.get(1);` seems completely pointless to me, so yes, the "traditional method" would be better in this case.

Comment: @JLRishe The point is to call .get() multiple times so that it's like a dynamic variable.

Comment: @Saposhiente Yeah, if you Java could implement Properties like in C# then all this could be avoided, alas!